Explicit geometric machinery to check the truth of FOL formula
It is standard to use the semantics of topological spaces for checking the truth value of propositional formula in the absence of excluded middle. An explicit description is written down here, for example.
https://grossack.site/2022/04/17/geometry-and-logic
I suppose, there might be possible to have something similar to determine the truth value of first order formulas. i.e. There might be a something to check on a topological space (as for propositional case, such a space is the real line) such that allows us to say a first order formula is true intuitionistically. I would guess it would be much more complicated, but does such a thing exist?

Yes, you can use a set $D$ and a topological space $X$ as a model of intuitionistic first-order logic.  To illustrate this, let me present a counterexample which shows that $[\forall x, \lnot\lnot \varphi(x)] \rightarrow \lnot\lnot \forall x, \varphi(x)$ is not an intuitionistic tautology.  (This is interesting because in intuitionistic logic, double negation does distribute over finite conjunctions $\land$, i.e. $\lnot\lnot(P\land Q)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot\lnot P) \land (\lnot\lnot Q)$; this counterexample will show that it does not distribute over "infinite conjunctions" $\forall$.)  For this counterexample, I will the topological space $\mathbb{R}$, and $D$ will also be $\mathbb{R}$, while the interpretation of $\varphi(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ will be $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x \}$.  Then for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, because $\varphi(x)$ is an open dense set, $\lnot\lnot \varphi(x)$ evaluates to all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore, $\forall x, \lnot\lnot \varphi(x)$ evaluates to all of $\mathbb{R}$.  On the other hand, the intersection of all sets $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x \}$ is the empty set, which implies that the interpretation of $\forall x, \varphi(x)$ is the empty set.  (Note that in general, because an arbitrary intersection of open sets is not necessarily open, you need to take the interior of the intersection to get the interpretation of $\forall$.)  Therefore, the interpretation of $\lnot\lnot(\forall x, \varphi(x))$ is also the empty set, and so the interpretation of $[\forall x, \lnot\lnot\varphi(x)] \rightarrow \lnot\lnot(\forall x, \varphi(x))$ is the empty set as well.

More generally, you can use a sheaf of sets $D$ on a topological space as a model of intuitionistic first-order logic.  Namely, for each $n$-ary function symbol, you can assign an interpretation to be a morphism of sheaves $D^n \to D$; and for each $n$-ary predicate symbol, you can assign an interpretation to be a morphism of sheaves $D^n \to \Omega$, or equivalently a subsheaf of $D^n$.  (Here, $\Omega$ is the subobject classifier, which in the case of a topological space is the sheaf of sets where $\Omega(U)$ is the set of open subsets of $U$, and the restriction maps $\Omega(U) \to \Omega(V)$ are $W \mapsto W \cap V$.)
As for how you interpret $\forall$ and $\exists$, that does indeed get slightly complicated.  To set up the semantics, suppose we have a formula $\varphi$ with $n$ free variables $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.  We will need to define for each open subset $U$ of the topological space, and for each assignment $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in D(U)$ of values for $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, whether
$$U \models \varphi(v_1 / x_1, \ldots, v_n / x_n).$$
Then the interpretation of a formula involving $\forall$ becomes: suppose $\varphi$ has free variables $x, v_1, \ldots, v_n$, so that $\forall x \varphi$ becomes a formula with free variables $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.  Then we define:
$$U \models (\forall x \varphi)(v_1/x_1, \ldots, v_n/x_n) \Leftrightarrow \\
\forall V \subseteq U, \forall y \in D(V), V \models \varphi(x/y, v_1/(x_1|_V), \ldots, v_n/(x_n|_V).$$
As for $\exists$, the interpretation is:
$$U \models (\exists x \varphi)(v_1/x_1, \ldots, v_n/x_n) \Leftrightarrow \\
\bigcup \{ V \subseteq U \mid \exists y \in D(V), V \models \varphi(x/y, v_1/(x_1|_V), \ldots, v_n/(x_n|_V) \} = U.$$
In other words, in order for $\exists x \varphi$ to become true at the level of $U$, there must be some open cover $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$ of $U$ and values $y_i \in D(V_i)$ such that substituting $y_i$ for $x$, the formula $\varphi$ becomes true at the level of $V_i$.
To round it out, the propositional connectives are interpreted as follows: $U \models \top$ is always true; $U \models \bot$ is always false; and:
$$U \models p \land q \Leftrightarrow (U \models p) \land (U \models q); \\
U \models p \lor q \Leftrightarrow \exists V, W \subseteq U, U = V \cup W \land (U \models p) \land (V \models q); \\
U \models p \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \forall V \subseteq U, (V \models p) \Rightarrow (V \models q); \\
U \models \lnot p \Leftrightarrow \forall V \subseteq U, \lnot(V \models p).$$
Finally, to interpret $=$: if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two term formulas using the function symbols, then $U \models (\sigma = \tau)(v_1/x_1, \ldots, v_n/x_n)$ is evaluated by whether the assignments of $n$-ary function symbols, when applied to $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, result in equal sections of $D(U)$.  Similarly, if $P$ is one of the $m$-ary predicate symbols, and $\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_m$ are term formulas using the function symbols, then $U \models [P(\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_m)](v_1/x_1, \ldots, v_m/x_m)$ is evaluated by "plugging in" $x_i$ for $v_i$ to get $m$ sections of $D(U)$, and then determining whether the $m$-tuple of results is in the subsheaf which we are using as the interpretation of $P$.
(And then, if you want to get truth values out in terms of open subsets, you can take the union of all subsets of $U$ such that the formula becomes true at that level -- or in the case of a formula with no free variables, take the union of all subsets of the topological space such that the formula becomes true at that level.  That makes sense in part because we can prove the following properties of the interpretation above: if $U \models \varphi(v_1/x_1, \ldots, v_n/x_n)$, then for every open subset $V\subseteq U$, we have $V\models \varphi(v_1/(x_1|_V), \ldots, v_n/(x_n|_V))$.  And in the other direction, if we have a cover of $U$ by open subsets, $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$, such that $V_i \models \varphi(v_1/(x_1|_{V_i}), \ldots, v_n/(x_n|_{V_i}))$ for each $i \in I$, then $U \models \varphi(v_1/x_1, \ldots, v_n/x_n)$.)

In fact, using the internal hom $\mathscr{Hom}$ as a model of function variables, and $\mathscr{Hom}({-}, \Omega)$ as a model of proposition variables, you can extend this more general construction to some second-order logic, or alternatively to an intuitionistic type theory.  One of my favorite examples along these lines is to use the sheaf of analytic functions $\mathfrak{S}$ on $\mathbb{C}$ to give an example of a failure of the axiom of choice, in the form "every surjective function has a right inverse".  In particular, if you consider the differentiation morphism $\frac{d}{dz} : \mathfrak{S} \to \mathfrak{S}$, then this is a surjective morphism of sheaves, essentially because every open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ can be covered by simply connected open sets.  On the other hand, given any putative right inverse $\int dz \in \mathscr{Hom}(\mathfrak{S}, \mathfrak{S})(U)$ for a nonempty subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, then $U$ contains a punctured disc $V$ and an analytic function $f$ on that punctured disc with no antiderivative on $V$, so there is no possibility for $(\int dz)(f)$ which must be a section of $\mathfrak{S}(V)$.  We conclude that the interpretation of "there exists a right inverse of $\frac{d}{dz}$" is the empty set.

Your question is a bit mixed up about whether you are working in intuitionistic first-order logic (i.e., with quantifiers) or intuitionistic propositional logic (i.e., without quantifiers). In both cases, the topological reading is very useful for supplying counter-examples to unprovable formulas.  The interpretation of intuitionistic propositional logic in the topology of the real line is complete, so any unprovable formula can be given a counter-example in that interpretation. However, I don't think that it leads to any useful decision procedure for intuistionic proposition logic: the most widely used approach to deciding intuistionistic proposal logic is via Kripke models. Intuistionistic first-order logic is undecidable.

Thank you for the answer! May I please ask for an example of proving a first order formula is not provable using topology?

I didn't say that you can't use a topological approach to proving a first-order formula. What I said is that a topological approach doesn't  lead to a useful decision procedure (because we don't have a decision procedure for the topological formulas).

This is not surprising because FOL itself, whether classical or not, is undecidable. But may I please ask for an explicit description of a topological semantics for FOL formulas as we did for propositional formulas in the link above?
